What is the significance of Jesus' formula of 'Sell up and Serve' in Matthew 19 to Church- run organisations?
We see in Mtt 19:21( NRSVCE),   the definitive answer Jesus gave to the rich young man who had come to him seeking eternal life:

Jesus said to him, ‘If you wish to be perfect, go, sell your possessions, and give the money to the poor, and you will have treasure in heaven; then come, follow me.’.

Note the instructions that Jesus gives: first, sell the material possession and then  give the proceeds  to the poor. In case the man was asked to lease out , free of rent, his property say agricultural land to poor farmers, he would be in a position to review his decision and reclaim the property on a later date. But, selling up means that he would have no further claim on the property. No wonder the young man left sad- faced !
Many Catholic churches across the world have significant measure of real estate holdings, much of which may have been received on donation at the time of the church-construction from the then rulers and benefactors. Administrative rules and regulations of the area have come to curtail their possession to a great extent. Of course, locally constructed churches incur expenses on upkeep and salaries of staff, which they meet out of the revenue from  immovable property. So, you can never expect a church administration to sell out its property and distribute the proceedings to the poor.   But then, was the 'Sell up and Serve formula'  that Jesus prescribed,  the outcome of a stand-alone incident ?
My question is: what is the significance of Jesus' formula of 'Sell up and Serve' in Matthew 19 to Church- run organisations ?

In Acts 2 the apostles taught this and the churches practiced this. Acts 2:44 - 45 - All the believers were together and had everything in common. 45 They sold property and possessions to give to anyone who had need.

@Biff  Yes, although Jesus addressed one individual in Mat. 19, the principles should be applied by all Christians, to themselves. How true are they being to Christ's calling to follow him with 'a single eye'? "You cannot serve God and Mammon." So, for church organisations to try to excuse themselves from those principles just will not do. I should have included that in my answer.

@Anne - Yes I was referring to the responsibility by the apostles to continue the teaching as doctrine, and the responsibility of the followers to obey the teaching even joyously. The church today acts as the final authority over believers. That is why we are followers of Christ and not followers of church. The churches have thrown truth (lampstands) to the ground mostly. Followers of Christ should "come out of her" and go into the fields (tabernacles) leaving their possessions behind and wait on the Lord. He is drawing near.

First, this question cuts right across almost every church-run organisation you can think of. Equally, nearly all Christian religious groups that are not Catholic need to face up to this same matter. Though only the 'catholicism' tag has been used, I will answer to that, confident that points will equally apply to non-Catholic groups. This means that I am not trying to single catholicism out, so please don't let anyone think I'm taking a swipe at it. I am not.
Second, what Jesus invited the rich ruler to do was addressed to him, personally, and not to any other individual. Jesus had examined this earnest young man with questions, the answers to which Jesus did not challenge. No doubt, even from his youth, this man had zealously endeavoured to keep those commands. Next, the man pursued his initial request, to know what he had to do to inherit eternal life, by asking, "What do I still lack?"
His motives for coming to Jesus were interesting. Knowing that the Law of God is perfect, he wanted to keep it perfectly, in expectation that THAT would give him the reward of eternal life. Jesus knew that no sinful person could perfectly keep the Law of God, but instead of opening up a theological discussion, he had his finger on the spiritual pulse of this young man, and knew that his love of money was preventing him. Therefore, he gently exposed the sin in his heart - setting great store by money and material possessions - by saying that, if he wanted to be perfect, to sell what he had, give to the poor, and then follow Jesus. Jesus assured him that that would give him treasures in heaven. No more needs to be said about this event with regard to the question.
Does it apply to modern-day church-run organisations? Well, some of those are devoted to doing charitable works, to help the poor. One example is Catholic orphanages / sheltered living for poor women, in India, which came to public attention a few decades ago with one elderly nun who was acclaimed as a wonderful example of humility, and poverty. Public attention caused huge donations to then flood into this charity. All well and good, if that money was devoted to changing peoples' lives for the better, helping them climb out of their poverty. Yet, what if a great deal of that money went straight to the main organisastion, to boost its coffers? There was certainly undeniable service going on. But selling up to help the poor? Or increasing the already fabulous wealth of the main organisation?
This does not touch on the property aspect asked about. Hardly any need, for history testifies to how the main religious organisation started accumulating a business portfolio, to this day. It might be argued by it that that account of the rich young ruler only addresses individuals, and not a religious establishment. Of course, there are lots of other things Jesus said to groups of believers about not going out to spread the gospel with money-bags or changes of clothing. Lovers of money never get off lightly in the Bible. So, the core question is, to what extent does love of money entangle those running religious organisastions?
With wealth comes power, and then corruption isn't long in spiritually killing individuals. (Or literally... a banker under a London bridge?) And it's individuals who need to answer questions, otherwise their deeds will find them out and they will be publicly exposed to shame as those who brought disgrace on the good name of our Lord. This has happened recently, more than once, in some Protestant, charitable organisations, but you do not ask about that. All I will mention is regarding the point about property; "expenses on upkeep and salaries of staff, which they meet out of the revenue from immovable property." In many Protestant, smaller, circles that is mainly met by voluntary donations from those attending those buildings for worship.
To sum up the answer regarding this neat, "Sell up and Serve" phrase: Church-run organisations are made up of myriad individuals. Usually a hierarchy, and although most might be volunteers, serving selflessly (even at cost to themselves), a few at "the top" invariably command high wages, make their living out of a full-time job, and enjoy prestige and perks. Those are the individuals who need to make sure that, before God, they have no love of money or possessions, despite that. Otherwise, Christian conscience should cause them to resign their living, but (frankly) I wouldn't hold my breath waiting, if I were you.

Up-voted +1. In the entire New Testament writings there is neither any requirement for, nor any report of, any buildings, any structured organisation, any funds, any hierarchy, There is just nothing there. There are just the redeemed, called out of the world, on pilgrimage, giving testimony to the name of Jesus Christ.

Thanks, Anne, for the soul stirring inputs.By the way, I had the privilege of attending Mass with Mother Theresa in Her Convent Chapel in Kolkata on a hot humid day in 1989. It has no ceiling fans or  microphone . If the Sisters of Charity recived more funds than could be spent on charity the Govt was always there to watch ! We have the Foreign Contribution Regulation Act in place .

"what Jesus invited the rich ruler to do was addressed to him, personally, and not to any other individual" — This is an important point. The "sell and serve" isn't a general principle for everyone; it was specific to the rich man. The general principle is, to be willing to give up whatever is most treasured by you in order to follow Christ. The man "went away sorrowful: for he had great possessions"; he wasn't willing and so put his love of wealth above love of God. Jesus wasn't telling the man to actually sell everything, he was simply pointing out that the man wouldn't be willing to.

While the admonition was given to a particular individual, that doesn't mean Jesus wasn't teaching a general principle.  Right afterwards he tells the man it's easier for camel to go through the eye of a needle than for a rich man to make it to heaven, and then the crowd asks who can be saved, implying they thought the principle was general and not just for the rich man.  In response, Jesus' disciples say they've left everything to follow him, and he commends them for doing so.

@NigelJ Don't the epistles spend a fair amount of time detailing the structure of the church, e.g. who can be a bishop, deacon, and how they are to organize to help the needy among them?  Also, disciplinary measures to kick people out of the church, if need be.

@yters Overseers are selected from the presbytery, which is the mature men of the congregations. Deacons look after such things as voluntary financial offerings. I see in this nothing like the vast hierarchies of titled and paid persons in the organisations today. There is no comparison.

@Anne - didn't Jesus require the disciples to do the same? Mt4 -  “Come, follow me,” Jesus said, “and I will send you out to fish for people.” At once they left their nets and followed him. They left their jobs and family to follow Jesus. Then again,  Jesus called them, and immediately they left the boat and their father and followed him. Isn't this the same principle? Leave everything behind and start a new life, making yourself poor so that you can become rich in the kingdom, even though it doesn't say anything about selling land since they had none. This is why it's harder for a rich man.
